# How can I update User's details in grails with spring security before login With Remember Me Check?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I am using grails where authetication is done by Spring Security.I need to unlock User's account before login

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=[IllegalArgumentException, UsernameNotFoundException])
```

UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

```
  User user = User.findByUsername(username)
  // Check and unlock account if 24 Hrs has been passed
  userService.checkAndUnlockAccountAfter24Hrs(user.id);
  if (!user) throw new NoStackUsernameNotFoundException()

  def roles = user.authorities

  // or if you are using role groups:
  // def roles = user.authorities.collect { it.authorities }.flatten().unique()

  def authorities = roles.collect {
     new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.authority)
  }

  return new MyUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
        !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
        !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id,
        user.name)
```

}

Now when I do login with Remember Me check, Then It shows error:

```
- 

    | Error 2017-04-18 12:24:40,426 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR
       [/].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context
       with path [] threw exception
           Message: retrieveUser returned null - a violation of the interface contract
               Line | Method
           ->>   76 | attemptAuthentication in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
           - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
           |     49 | doFilter              in     ''
           |     82 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
           |    100 | doFilter              in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
           |   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
           |    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
           ^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: What do you mean by unlock Users account before login?

Answer (score -1):

You have three options:

1. Comment out that code in `boostrap` in every run; except first time.
2. Drop database and create database for every single run
3. Hacky way:

Use `condition(ternary operator)` like this:

```
def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ? : new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ? : new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

def adminUser = User.findByUsername('admin') ? : new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin', enabled: true).save(flush: true)
def user = User.findByUsername('user') ? : new User(username: 'user', password: 'user', enabled: true).save(flush: true)

if (!adminUser.authorities.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
  UserRole.create(adminUser, adminRole)
}
if (!user.authorities.contains('ROLE_USER')) {
  UserRole.create(user, userRole)
}
```